# Is it possible in Joomla to display Cached pages differently to Mobile and Desktop users

Tags: templates, caching, joomla

I am facing an issue - wherein due to cache enabling -

> mobile template is shown on desktop and
>
> desktop template is shown on mobile (sometimes basis cache page stored in),

Is it possible in any way so that cache can be disabled on templates and only store in the content and basis template displayed on mobile or desktop - correct template is shown in rather than cached version of template as stored

I am sorry, as its not a direct coding question - but i guess a small line of code may help in achieving the desired, can anyone help in it pls